# Django manytomany field holding Users autofilling

Tags: python, django, django-users, manytomanyfield

I am pulling data from a json file on the web, and updating it in my django database. I want to keep track of users that are associated with each team, but as soon as a user loads the page once they are added to the model. How do I avoid this?

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    wins = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    losses = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ties = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

```
def getTeams():
    import requests
    baseUrl = "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/"

    # INITALIZING THE DATA IN THE DATA DICTIONARY
    r = requests.get(baseUrl + '/api/v1/teams')
    originalData = r.json()
    # i dont need the copyright, only care about the teams
    originalData = originalData["teams"]
    for team in originalData:
        id = team["id"]
        try:
            databaseTeam = Team.objects.get(id = id)
        except Exception:
            Team.objects.create(id = id)
            databaseTeam = Team.objects.get(id = id)
        databaseTeam.name = team["name"]
        databaseTeam.abbreviation = team["abbreviation"]
        databaseTeam.link = team["link"]
        databaseTeam.save()
    print("done")

@login_required
def myTeamView(request):
    t1 = Thread(target=getTeams)
    t1.start()
    return(render(request, "teams/myTeams.html", {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

The user is stored on **user** variable inside the request, so first we need to pass it to `getTeams` method. Then we use the method `add` of Manytomany fields to append an record to it, in this case the user.

```py
def getTeams(request):
    import requests
    baseUrl = "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/"

    # INITALIZING THE DATA IN THE DATA DICTIONARY
    r = requests.get(baseUrl + '/api/v1/teams')
    originalData = r.json()
    # i dont need the copyright, only care about the teams
    originalData = originalData["teams"]
    for team in originalData:
        id = team["id"]
        try:
            databaseTeam = Team.objects.get(id = id)
        except Exception:
            Team.objects.create(id = id)
            databaseTeam = Team.objects.get(id = id)
        databaseTeam.name = team["name"]
        databaseTeam.abbreviation = team["abbreviation"]
        databaseTeam.link = team["link"]
        databaseTeam.save()
        databaseTeam.users.add(request.user) # after save!!
    print("done")

@login_required
def myTeamView(request):
    t1 = Thread(target=getTeams, args=(request, ))
    t1.start()
    return(render(request, "teams/myTeams.html", {}))
```

Comment: Yup, I got that, but even without that, the database still stores every single user, regardless of whether or not I add it. I'm trying to find a way around that.

Comment: If I add one user, every single user in the database gets added, which is what I am trying to find a solution to.